# How to filter an array of objects by the element inside an inner array - Functional Programming Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Still working my way through functional programming: .forEach(), .map(), .filter(), .reduce().

I'm working through a new challenge.

```
var bikes = [
   {name: 'Cinelli Bolt', price: '2000', age: 1, singlespeed: 'yes', features: ['tubeless tires', 'disk brakes', 'carbon frame']},
   {name: 'Cinelli Mash', price: '1700', age: 3, singlespeed: 'yes', features: ['gatorskin tyres', 'sram drivetrain', 'steel frame']},
   {name: 'Specialized Langster', price: '1000', age: 1, singlespeed: 'no', features: ['two speed enclosed hub', 'bullbars', 'carbon frame']}
 ];
```

I'm trying to filter the array by a specific feature 'carbon frame'. I was thinking about using filter but I'm confused about calling the feature inside the key.value pair.

```
var justCarbonBikes = bikes.filter(function(bike) {
  return bike.features['carbon frame'];
});
```

Expected result should modify the original array:

```
var bikes = [
   {name: 'Cinelli Bolt', price: '2000', age: 1, singlespeed: 'yes', features: ['tubeless tires', 'disk brakes', 'carbon frame']},
   {name: 'Specialized Langster', price: '1000', age: 1, singlespeed: 'no', features: ['two speed enclosed hub', 'bullbars', 'carbon frame']}
 ];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were almost there. With the check of the index with [`Array#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf), you could use it as return value.

```
return bike.features.indexOf('carbon frame') + 1;
```

```js
var bikes = [{ name: 'Cinelli Bolt', price: '2000', age: 1, singlespeed: 'yes', features: ['tubeless tires', 'disk brakes', 'carbon frame'] }, { name: 'Cinelli Mash', price: '1700', age: 3, singlespeed: 'yes', features: ['gatorskin tyres', 'sram drivetrain', 'steel frame'] }, { name: 'Specialized Langster', price: '1000', age: 1, singlespeed: 'no', features: ['two speed enclosed hub', 'bullbars', 'carbon frame'] }],
    justCarbonBikes = bikes.filter(function(bike) {
        return bike.features.indexOf('carbon frame') + 1;
    }),
    bikesWithoutCarbon = bikes.filter(function(bike) {
        return bike.features.indexOf('carbon frame') === -1;
    });

console.log(justCarbonBikes);
console.log(bikesWithoutCarbon);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

ES6 with [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) as return value.

```js
var bikes = [{ name: 'Cinelli Bolt', price: '2000', age: 1, singlespeed: 'yes', features: ['tubeless tires', 'disk brakes', 'carbon frame'] }, { name: 'Cinelli Mash', price: '1700', age: 3, singlespeed: 'yes', features: ['gatorskin tyres', 'sram drivetrain', 'steel frame'] }, { name: 'Specialized Langster', price: '1000', age: 1, singlespeed: 'no', features: ['two speed enclosed hub', 'bullbars', 'carbon frame'] }],
    justCarbonBikes = bikes.filter(b => b.features.includes('carbon frame')),
    bikesWithoutCarbon = bikes.filter(b => !b.features.includes('carbon frame'));

console.log(justCarbonBikes);
console.log(bikesWithoutCarbon);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: How could I negate the function: all bikes that are don't have a feature of 'carbon frame'?

Comment: you could check the result or negate it, as with includes.

Answer (score 1):

This is one solution, you can loop through features inside the filter function and return if you find carbon frame

```
var justCarbonBikes = bikes.filter(function(bike) {
  for(let i of bike.features){
    if(i == 'carbon frame'){
      return bike
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Nice, I prefer this to filter because you could specific agains a certain criteria: if I wanted all of the bikes that weren't carbon frames. 